# How to install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, 13.10

How do I install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Ubuntu 12.10. Thank You. Steven50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install Ubuntu **12.04 LTS**.

Then attempt to install **13.10** (latest). It will prompt you to install *alongside* **OR** *replacing* **12.04**.

---

*If you have a more detailed question, please add to your earlier question ..*